# Weird FFT plot with numpy random set

Tags: python, numpy, fft, intel-mkl

Code below:

```
import numpy as np 
from numpy import random_intel
import mkl_fft
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n = 10**5
a = np.random_intel.rand(n)
b = mkl_fft.fft(a)
plt.scatter(b.real,b.imag)
plt.show()
print(b)
for i in b :
    if i.real > n/2:
        print("Weird FFT Number is ",i)
```

Result is :
[image: output]

You can see:

```
Weird FFT Number is  (50020.99077289924+0j)
```

Why FFT with random set came out one particular number?

---

(Thanks to Paul Panzer & SleuthEye)

With `mkl_fft.fft(a-0.5)` the final result is:
[image: final result]

---

[2019/03/29 Updated]

With normalized data everything went well

`b = mkl_fft.fft((a - np.mean(a))/np.std(a))`

The average value of  `(a - np.mean(a))/np.std(a)` is near zero

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the constant or zero frequency mode, which is essentially the mean of your signal. You are sampling uniformly from the unit interval, so the mean is ~0.5. Some fft implementations scale this with the number of points to save a multiplication.

Answer (score 2):

The large value in the FFT output happens to be the very first one which corresponds to the DC component. This indicates that the input has a non-zero average value over the entire data set.

Indeed if you look closer at the input data, you might notice that the values are always between 0 and 1, with an average value around 0.5. This is consistent with the `rand` function implementation which provides pseudo-random samples drawn from a uniform distribution over [0, 1).

You may confirm this to be the case by subtracting the average value with

```
b = mkl_fft.fft(a - np.mean(a))
```

and noting that the large initial value `b[0]` should be near zero.

Comment: _"decreases significantly to be of similar magnitude as the others"_ Don't think so, should be zero up to numerical noise. Whereas the other modes should be distinct from zero.

Comment: I based that statement on the fact that typically a random variable with zero expected value would still have some non-zero average value, but you are right that in this specific case where the mean is constructed to be exactly zero, `b[0]` should be very near zero.

Comment: Yep, I think you are correct if instead of the sample mean you subtract the true mean, which should be 0.5 (-resolution/2 if we want to be pedantic).

Comment: I found out a ultimate solution :`b = mkl_fft.fft((a - np.mean(a))/np.std(a))`